# Lazy Math with C++ Ranges

Tags: c++, lazy-evaluation, c++20, range-v3

I wanted to explore the realm of lazy mathematical operations in c++ using ranges (specifically range-v3), rather than expression templates.  Instead of defining the various operators :`operator+`, `operator-`, ... and so on, to accept all ranges, I thought it would be prudent to provide a wrapper class and define the operations on the wrapper class which I've called `result_range` in the code below.  I'm getting some compiler errors due to how the `end_cursor` method is implemented.  The code pasted below is also on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Ycv663). The code:

```cpp
#include <range/v3/core.hpp>
#include <range/v3/range/concepts.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/repeat.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/repeat_n.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/zip.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/zip_with.hpp>
#include <range/v3/algorithm/equal.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>
#include <functional>

namespace vs = ranges::views;
namespace rs = ranges;

template <ranges::input_range R>
struct result_range;

namespace detail
{
// define some traits and concepts to constrain our universal references and ranges
template <typename = void>
struct is_result : std::false_type {
};
template <typename T>
struct is_result<result_range<T>> : std::true_type {
};

template <typename U>
constexpr bool is_result_v = is_result<std::remove_cvref_t<U>>::value;

} // namespace detail

template <typename T>
concept Result = detail::is_result_v<T>;

template <typename T>
concept Numeric = std::integral<T> || std::floating_point<T>;

template <ranges::input_range R>
struct result_range : ranges::view_facade<result_range<R>> {
private:
    friend ranges::range_access;
    R r;

    struct cursor {
    private:
        using It = ranges::iterator_t<R>;
        It iter;

    public:
        // using contiguous = ;

        cursor() = default;
        cursor(It it) : iter(it) {}

        decltype(auto) read() const { return *iter; }
        decltype(auto) read() { return *iter; }

        bool equal(const cursor& other) const { return iter == other.iter; }

        void next() { ++iter; }

        void prev() requires ranges::bidirectional_iterator<It> { --iter; }

        auto distance_to(const cursor& other) const
            -> decltype(ranges::distance(iter, other.iter))
        {
            return ranges::distance(iter, other.iter);
        }

        auto advance(std::ptrdiff_t n) -> decltype(ranges::advance(iter, n))
        {
            ranges::advance(iter, n);
        }
    };

    cursor begin_cursor() const { return {ranges::begin(r)}; }
    cursor begin_cursor() { return {ranges::begin(r)}; }

    cursor end_cursor() const { return {ranges::end(r)}; }
    cursor end_cursor() { return {ranges::end(r)}; }

public:
    result_range() = default;

    result_range(R&& r) : r{std::forward<R>(r)} {}
};

template <typename R>
result_range<R> result(R&& r)
{
    return {std::forward<R>(r)};
}

#define gen_operators(op, f)                                                             \
    template <Result T, Result U>                                                        \
    constexpr auto op(T&& t, U&& u)                                                      \
    {                                                                                    \
        return result(vs::zip_with(f, std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<U>(u)));          \
    }                                                                                    \
    template <Result T, Numeric U>                                                       \
    constexpr auto op(T&& t, U u)                                                        \
    {                                                                                    \
        if constexpr (ranges::sized_range<T>)                                            \
            return result(                                                               \
                vs::zip_with(f, std::forward<T>(t), vs::repeat_n(u, t.size())));         \
        else                                                                             \
            return result(vs::zip_with(f, std::forward<T>(t), vs::repeat(u)));           \
    }                                                                                    \
    template <Result T, Numeric U>                                                       \
    constexpr auto op(U u, T&& t)                                                        \
    {                                                                                    \
        if constexpr (ranges::sized_range<T>)                                            \
            return result(                                                               \
                vs::zip_with(f, vs::repeat_n(u, t.size()), std::forward<T>(t)));         \
        else                                                                             \
            return result(vs::zip_with(f, vs::repeat(u), std::forward<T>(t)));           \
    }
gen_operators(operator+, std::plus{})
gen_operators(operator-, std::minus{})
gen_operators(operator*, std::multiplies{})
gen_operators(operator/, std::divides{})

int main()
{
    auto x_ = std::vector{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    auto y_ = std::vector{-1, -2, -3, -4, -5};
    auto x = result(x_ | vs::all);
    auto y = result(y_ | vs::all);

    auto sum = x + y + 2 * x - y + 3 * y;

    std::cout << "sum is 0? " << rs::equal(sum, vs::repeat_n(0, 5)) << '\n';
}
```

And the first error:

```
<source>:134:67:   required from here
<source>:82:49: error: could not convert '{ranges::_end_::fn::operator()(R&&) const [with R = ranges::zip_with_view<std::multiplies<void>, ranges::repeat_n_view<int>, result_range<ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > >&; ranges::_end_::fn::_result_t<R> = ranges::iter_zip_with_view<ranges::indirected<std::multiplies<void> >, ranges::repeat_n_view<int>, result_range<ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > >::sentinel<false>](((result_range<ranges::zip_with_view<std::multiplies<void>, ranges::repeat_n_view<int>, result_range<ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > > >*)this)->result_range<ranges::zip_with_view<std::multiplies<void>, ranges::repeat_n_view<int>, result_range<ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > > >::r)}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'result_range<ranges::zip_with_view<std::multiplies<void>, ranges::repeat_n_view<int>, result_range<ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > > >::cursor'
   82 |     cursor end_cursor() { return {ranges::end(r)}; }
      |                                                 ^
      |                                                 |
      |                                                 <brace-enclosed initializer list>

ASM generation compiler returned: 1
```

Question: What is the correct way to implement the `result_range` facade?  Normally I can figure out the correct usage from the extensive tests in range-v3 but there's only one test for `view_facade` so I can't glean the correct usage.